# SQL - find the correct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I've got this problem

in this table i've registered for each amount the relative discount

```
Amount   Discount
 500        5%
1000       10%
1200       11%
2100       15%
```

ecc...

In another table i've got the gross price of the order for example 2000 how i can find the correct discount for this order? In that case 11% because 2100 > 2000 ?

Comment: Which database (Oracle, mySql, sql Server...)?

Comment: oh i've forgot to said that, i'm using sql server

Answer (score 1):

With `top`:

```
select top 1 Discount 
from Discounts
where Amount <= 2000
order by Amount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select discount
  from tq84_discount
 where amount = (
  select max(amount)
   from tq84_discount
  where amount <= 2000
 );
```

Test data:

```
create table tq84_discount (
  amount number,
  discount number
);

insert into tq84_discount values (  0, 0);
insert into tq84_discount values (500, 5);
insert into tq84_discount values (100, 10);
insert into tq84_discount values (1200, 11);
insert into tq84_discount values (2100, 15);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! Can you help me also with this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968178/sql-recursion-statement-trigger/30984262#30984262 thanks a lot for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 Discount
from Discounts
where Amount < GrossPrice
orderby Amount desc
```

This simple query works. GrossPrice is the variable in which it has the value from other table. 2000 in this case.